# Replacing all but alphabetic characters with spaces in python, in any language

Tags: python-2.x, unicode-string

The code

```
phrase = "".join([c if c.isalpha() else " " for c in phrase])
```

substitute all non-alphabetic character with spaces. It works very well with strings made up with occidental language characters.

But giving it the value:

```
phrase = u'इसका स्वामित्व और नियंत्रण किया। इसके'
```

the result is `u'इसक  स व म त व और न य त रण क य   इसक '`, while it shouldn't change, since the string is only made of alphabetic characters and spaces.

I think the reason is that some character is a *surrogate pair*.

Is it a bug with python's `isalpha()` method?

Or, if not, how can I deal properly with characters represented by surrogate pairs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Python2 is implied by his use of `u''`

Comment: also, not quite sure what you *want* to happen to that string?

Comment: I want to leave all alphabetic characters and replace non-alphabetic ones with spaces

Comment: that one I got, but what about things like `´`, which can be used as *combining diacritic* in unicode! Basically, there's two ways to write `café`; one consisting of four unicode codepoints `c`, `a`, `f`, `é`, and one consisting of five: `c`, `a`, `f`, `e`, `´`. Your rule would not touch the first one `café`->`café`, but would mutilate the second: `café`->`cafe `.